# Passing a multidimensional array to a function in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was just trying an maze-mouse game, to retain the position of the mouse in array,

I created a multidimensional array in python

```
maze = [[0 for x in range(8)] for x in range(8)]
```

and I called a function using

```
l = move_mouse(m,maze)
```

function is

```
def move_mouse(m,maze =[i][j]):
    if m=='down':
       i = i+1
       return maze
```

How to pass the array with with values `i` and `j` in `maze` so that to retain the current position and return the same to main function?

Please tell if I'm wrong in assigning it.

Comment: What are you actually storing in maze? Is it only to record the position of the mouse in the maze, or are there other items (e.g. blocks of cheese, cats, mouse traps, etc)?

Comment: Its only to record position of the mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maze and the position are two different objects, you cannot mix them in a way you tried. Keep them separate:

```
def move_mouse(m, maze, pos):
    if m == 'down':
        # check the maze
        pos = pos[0], pos[1] + 1
    return pos

maze = [[0 for x in range(8)] for x in range(8)]
pos = (4,4)

pos = move_mouse('down', maze, pos)
```